# Prove using definitions. Only one straight line can pass through 2 points.

Tags: geometry

Real plane $ R^2 $ is defined as a set whose elements are pairs of real numbers $ p = (p_1, p_2) $

Straight line on such a plane, is a point which moves evenly in a given direction. $ p + v*t = (p_1, p_2) + (v_1, v_2) * t $

Using these definitions, I have to prove two theorems:

> Only one straight line L can pass through any 2 points.

> Only one straight line, that does not intersect with L, passes through any point, that does not lie on L

I  know that this is so obvious, but because I am a novice in mathematics, I can't prove it. Could you please provide well-written proof ?

UPD: I have constructed proof for the first one.

> Since straight line can move only in a given direction, it is obvious
> that if a line intersects point X, there is only a single path to
> intersect point Y. Therefore, there can be only a single line

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: @Aryadeva Since straight line can move only in a given direction, it is obvious that if a line intersects point X, there is only a single path to intersect point Y. Therefore, there can be only a single line.

Comment: Good. You should add all your thoughts to your question. Otherwise it will be closed or  deleted  Rustem Sadykov